# How can I resize the checkmark for checkbox?

Tags: css

Recently I've made custom CSS only (imageless) checkmarks and radio buttons.

I've used this piece of CSS code for checkmark `content: "\2714";`, but I have issues with sizing that checkmark, it stays "small" no matter what, any idea how can I make it bigger?

Comment: Can we see your actual CSS? Which element are you applying the `content` to, and what does your HTML look like (or does it not matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

font-size seems to work just fine for me in FF 10:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    p:before {
        content: "\2714";
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello there</p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Chrome and Safari also seem to work with no issue.

Comment: Should work across every browser that supports these pseudo-elements.